# Difference between Openzeppelin SDK and Truffle?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle, openzeppelin

For smart contract development, what is the difference between Openzeppelin SDK and Truffle? When should I use one or another, or both together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**OpenZeppelin Contracts**: library of SmartContracts, that can be inherited and used to develop upon;

**OpenZeppelin SDK**: is former ZeppelinOS, it is SDK to help development process;

**Truffle SDK**: is well-known SDK to help development process as well. Besides SDK Truffle has other great projects as Ganache.

Spend some time to read documentation - it is very clear documented.

PS: ZeppelinOS was first SDK, that allowed to develop *Upgradable Smart Contracts* - really cool (https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-create-an-upgradeable-smart-contract-using-openzeppelin-sdk-example-of-fixing-smart-260dfbfd5bae)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Keeping things simple:

Truffle is a setup tool you can use to develop smart contracts, but doesn't touch Solidity code at all. It is like [Cargo](https://crates.io/) to Rust or npm/yarn to NodeJS.

OpenZeppelin is a well-tested set of libraries written in Solidity that you can import to your smart contracts while code is potentially being generated, maintained and deployed by truffle.

Comment: The question is about OpenZeppein SDK, not OpenZeppelin Contracts

Answer (score -2):

**OpenZepplin SDK and Truffle**

**OpenZepplin**

> is a library which consist of well documented smart contracts which you can use in your projects. You can import Openzepplin library in your solidity project in order to use it. 
>    The most obvious use of this library is for the ERC720 and ERC721 implementation.Their upgradeability concept is also one of the best.

**Truffle**:

> is a development framework which you can use for your solidity
>   project. It can help you to test your developed solidity contracts by
>   compiling and migrating it on local test network. You can interact
>   with the deployed contracts thereafter either manually by using
>   truffle console or by running unit test which are written in
>   Javascript with Mocha and chai.

While building any solidity project where you are required to develop smart contracts which can use ERC token implementation or any other implementation than **Openzepplin** is one of the selected choice. 
After your development in order to check the functionality and working of the smart contracts you developed **Truffle** is used.

Comment: "is a library which consist" - this refers to OpenZeppelin Contracts, but question is regarding to the OpenZeppelin SDK. Your answer is misleading :)